# Create vbscript messagebox that stays on top and blocks other windows

Tags: vbscript, messagebox

Help me please to create a messagebox which stays always on top, and user can't use other windows functions like calling start menu or interacting with other windows until he presses the OK button on messagebox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second parameter of the `MsgBox` function allows you to specify options for the dialog.

```
MsgBox "Hello, World!", vbSystemModal
```

For more information, see my article [Mastering the Message Box](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/VB.NET/Mastering-the-Message-Box/).

Comment: Both vbOKOnly and vbSystemModal don't block other windows. Is it even possible?

Comment: On Win16 systems, all applications are suspended until the user reacts to the message box.  On more modern Win32 systems, the message box will remain on top of other windows but the behavior is application modal.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the "vbInformation" mark and a Title to the Message Box. "+" is needed before "vbSystemModal".

MsgBox "Hello, World!", vbinformation +vbSystemModal, "Message Title.."

***OR***

MsgBox "Hello, World!", 64 +vbSystemModal, "Message Title.."

Answer (score -3):

MsgBox "Hello, World!", +vbSystemModal

Make sure to add the "+" before vbSystemModal

Comment: Why the negative vote anonymous one? What did you see?! https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png

Comment: I'd guess because this answer doesn't add anything to the accepted answer and the "+" requirement isn't true AFAICT