# How to make vbs message box "always on top"

Tags: vbscript

I came across one or two posts on this topic, such as:

[Create vbscript messagebox that stays on top and blocks other windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394432/create-vbscript-messagebox-that-stays-on-top-and-blocks-other-windows)

but this doesn't seem to work with an 'if.. else' argument. Whenever I try to add anything of the like to the second line of my script, I get WSH VBScript compilation error messages.

This is the script, and I am trying to make it remain visible above all other windows which open on the screen after it has appeared. Would appreciate help. Thanks,

Martin

```
intAnswer = _
Msgbox("           Do you want to run FS Earth?", _
    vbYesNo, " ")

If intAnswer = vbYes Then

Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""D:\FS9\FS_Earth\fs_earth_link.exe""")
Set objShell = Nothing

Else    

End If
```

Answer (score 4):

I spent a good 5 minutes reading your question over and over again..I feel a bit silly - it finally dawned on me what you were asking!

Currently, you can't add anything on line two, because **your first three lines of code are actually a single instruction spanned across multiple lines (by use of the underscore _ character)**.

If you rewrote your code as below, you could certainly add whatever you like between line 1 and 2 :)

```
intAnswer = Msgbox("Do you want to run FS Earth?", vbYesNo + vbSystemModal, " ")

If intAnswer = vbYes Then
    Dim objShell
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
    objShell.Run("""D:\FS9\FS_Earth\fs_earth_link.exe""")
    Set objShell = Nothing
Else    

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't really control the layering because those other windows are separate processes and the msgbox belongs to the process that launched the vbs.

Comment: The example in the link I gave certainly works - the message box stays above any other window I open afterwards. You mean that, because I open another programme from within the vbs script, it works differently? Why would it? (Genuine question!). Thanks. Martin

Comment: to me it looks like your are shelling out the fs_earth_link.exe application, that is most likely just another process now with no parent/child relationship. a Modal Msgbox is modal for the process it belongs to.