# How to create a Modal Msgbox in VBS

Tags: vbscript

I'm having trouble making a Msgbox modal. Every time I add ', +vbSystemModal' to the end, it just breaks my script saying -Invalid procedure call or argument: 'Msgbox'-

I'm using something similar to the following code (but, longer, with more calls and stuff)

```
MsgBox "Hello " & objUser.givenName & ", Please note that your password Expires in " & daysLeft & " day(s)" & " at " & whenPasswordExpires & chr(13) & chr(13) & "You have less than one day left! It is advised that you update your password immediately to avoid network issues." & chr(13) & chr(13) &  "Please press CTRL-ALT-DEL and select the 'Change a password' option before your password expires!", "PASSWORD EXPIRATION WARNING!", +vbSystemModal
```

Is it calling the daysleft and username that breaks it? How can I work around this to make it a modal message?

thanks in advance.

EDIT: As explained above, using ", +vbSystemModal" simply breaks the script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create vbscript messagebox that stays on top and blocks other windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394432/create-vbscript-messagebox-that-stays-on-top-and-blocks-other-windows)

Comment: Please post the full call you make that errors, so far you have just posted the string minus the `MsgBox`??

Answer (score 2):

Using the following worked:

```
MsgBox "Message goes here!", 4096, "Title of message!"
```

The 4096 sets it as a Msgbox with an 'OK' option and modal settings.

This works better than ", +vbSystemModal" when your message is broken up as you call information.

Comment: Sounds like you had a syntax error in there, hard to determine seen as though you didn't provide a clear code sample of the `MsgBox()` call in the initial question. You see `4096` is the numeric value of the named constant `vbSystemModal` so both should work. I'm not sure what the `+` is all about, you only need that if you are ORing bit flags, so say you wanted OK and Cancel but also an application modal message box you would specify `vbOKCancel + vbSystemModal`. If you just wanted the application modal message box you would use `vbSystemModal` no `+` necessary.

Comment: Does it error if you write `MsgBox "Message goes here!", vbSystemModal, "Title of message!"`?

Comment: @Lankymart no it doesn't break, which is why I thought it might be what I was calling in the longer script. As for the +, I'm brand new to VBS, and a tutorial for modal Msgbox's that I found only said 'Always remember the +', so I just ran with it

Comment: In which case update your answer and use that, it's never a good idea to use literal numeric values when the named constants exist.